# Background-image scroll function not working

Tags: html, css, position, background-image

This might sound stupid but I've got a background as an image on a web and I want it to scroll with page scroll. I looked on the internet how it is done and it's still not working for me, even tho I, at least I hope, I've got it right. I haven't work with Html/CSS in a while so I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

```
header.masthead::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(/assets/img/gradient-bg.jpg);
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(-20deg, #2b5876 0%, #4e4376 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-attachment: scroll;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

<header class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="mainH1" class="mastshead-subheading" style="color: white" ;>Find ideal <span
                    style="font-weight: 700;color: rgb(140,113,255);">mouse</span> for your hand</h1>
            <h2 class="mastshead-subheading" style="font-weight: 700;color: rgb(140,113,255);"> Select your screen
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 2rem;"
                    data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Diagonal should be written in info box on back side of your computer screen.
                    Google model of your monitor (written on back side of your computer screen).
                    Measure it with ruler (1 inch = 2.54 cm).">diagonal<sup> ?</sup></button> in inches
            </h2>
            <div class="text text-white"
                style="display:inline-block;background:transparent;border:none;font-weight:600;font-size:1.15rem;margin:0;"
                role="alert">
                <u>Make sure that your browser zoom is set to 100%</u>
            </div>
            <div id="inches-wrapper">
                <select id="inches" class="selectpicker" title="''" data-style="btn-warning" data-dropup-auto="false"
                    data-display="static" style="color:grey !important; font-size: 50px;">
                </select>
                <div id="manual-inches-wrapper">
                    <input id="manual-inches" placeholder="''" autocomplete="off">
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" id="inches-confirm">OK</button>
                    <br>
                    <div class="alert" id=alert>Wrong input</div>
                </div>
                <!--
                <div class="bubble" id="firstBubble">
                    <img class="bubble-img" src="assets/img/step1-2.png">
                </div>
                -->
            </div>
            <!-- js-scroll-trigger in js code-->
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Post your html as well

Comment: I did not make this page, I am just helping a friend with it and the code is kinda mess. Sorry

Comment: What does "I want it to scroll with page scroll" mean?

Comment: Basically, if I scroll with my mouse the background will move also and won't stay in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the image to a separate dive it will work.

```
<header>....</header>
<div class="background-image"></div>

header{
  height:200vh;
}

.background-image {
  content: "";
   background-image: url(https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTI2YTlhMWMtNWY1Mi00NGQ3LWFkMjEtZjI3NmUzYjI1NWFmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_.jpg); 
/* background-image: linear-gradient(-20deg, #2b5876 0%, #4e4376 100%);*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I set the header height to 2*viewhieght so that the scroll bar would be needed.

https://codepen.io/shaniemoonlight/pen/WNoQOXj

Comment: I edited my code as you answered, but it is still not working. I might be wrong with editing but I used the exact code.